# WCF MessageSecurityException: The security timestamp is invalid because its creation time

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have an app that connects to our WCF service to send data.
It uses custom user validation to authenticate the user.

Currently, if the client time is significantly different to our server's (the default 5 mins), then this error will fault the connection.

I'm trying to catch this specific error so that on the server side, I can notify someone when it occurs and for the user/client that it occurred for.

I want to do this because allowing a larger clock skew won't solve our problem, there can be huge variation on the client's machine times. We don't control the client machines, however we can get them to update their time.

I have tried to put a generic try/catch in the validate method, and that does capture other exceptions (like if the authentication fails - I throw a FaultException) , it doesn't seem to catch the clock skew issue. I'm guessing this isn't the correct place to catch this, but I'm at a loss as to where else it should go.

I would implement passing the client time as part of the login (as I have seen suggested elsewhere), however I'm not able to do this at this time and really need a way to identify clients with incorrect date/times in the meantime.

If it helps, the service is using: **basicHttpBinding** and its security mode is: **TransportWithMessageCredential**

Comment: If you know the MessageSecurityExpeption how is it that you can't responde to it?

Comment: Apologies - I should have mentioned, I have diagnostics implemented in the web.config so I can see the activity being logged (hence how I know the exceptions are occurring). Good question @Blam